# Can the artificer Magical Tinkering be used to falsify documents?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, artificer

> **Magical Tinkering.** A static visual effect appears on one of the object’s surfaces. This
>   effect can be a picture, up to 25 words of text, lines and shapes, or
>   a mixture of these elements, as you like.

If I had an identification paper, could the class ability be used to replace some of the words and the image on the paper? Or maybe be used to create a "fake" emblem on the document?

Comment: I often wonder what effects and uses *Magical Tinkering* would have in gameplay.  I haven't yet had the chance to be incredibly creative with it.  I foresee it being able to cover up text as well since it does not specify that the background can still be seen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**

In a way, a magical feature that allows you to place pictures and text onto a surface is not that different to anyone else just doing the same manually with ink and paint.

Since anyone can attempt to use ink and paint to forge a document, there's no reason why the artificer ability couldn't do the same.

The mundane case would likely call for a Charisma(Deception) check or Dexterity(Sleight of Hand) to produce something of appropriate quality. As a DM I might still call for the same check even if the document was produced via artificer magic, though possibly with advantage since it sounds like it should be easier to use this magic (this is where a DM would just have to go with the flow and house-rule a little bit).